# Is it possible to lock excel file with password using VBA for just specific date/time?

Tags: excel, vba, time, password-protection

I'm currently creating macro-driven file for excel where fairly sizeable amounts of data are uploaded via .csv files, and redistributed to different tabs according to some rules. (Sadly no direct link to database)
This happens every Friday until 12:00AM, and during that time - 8:00 - 12:00 I would like to make the file password protected. So only person responsible for loading of all of the data can use that file.

Because it's a shared file that's working on SharePoint with auto-save feature, a lot of people want to use it simultaneously. But excel and shared features don't really like multiple people while macros are running in the background. So can I pop some MsgBox on Workbook.open() with information about the file not being currently available and requiring password to proceed if day == Friday, time between 8-12?

Comment: I think you can. Make a sub to protect the worksheet in discussion and another one to un-protect it. The first one will call the next and vice versa (using `Application.OnTime`). Then some other sub routines to call them. Firstly, put a piece of code in the workbook `Open` event, able do reed the current data and calculate when to be the first run of protecting sub. You can also do it in some other sheet events. Maybe a `Public` `Date` variable, keeping the moment of sub running will be helpful when the other events code will evaluate the situation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

```
Function unlockwb()

pw = "mypassword1"
' Unprotect WB structure
ThisWorkbook.Unprotect pw
' Unrotect sheet
Sheet1.Unprotect pw

End Function

Function lockwb()

pw = "mypassword1"
' Protect WB structure
ThisWorkbook.Protect pw, True, True
' Protect sheet
Sheet1.Protect pw

End Function

Sub LockOnTime()
'Unlock all, lock again if condition(s) is/are satisfied
unlockwb

' Lock by day of the week
weekdaylock = vbFriday
If Weekday(Date) = weekdaylock Then
    lockwb
End If

' Or lock by time
timelowerbound = TimeValue("11:00:00 AM")
timeupperbound = TimeValue("12:00:00 PM")
If timelowerbound < Time() And Time() < timeupperbound Then
    lockwb
End Sub

' Or both
If Weekday(Date) = weekdaylock Then
    If timelowerbound < Time() And Time() < timeupperbound Then
        lockwb
    End Sub
End If
```

Comment: Your function to protect must be called by an event (at least) and another function to unlock the worksheet must also  be created and called by the first function (probably, using `Application.OnTime` will be good).

Comment: What do you mean "must be called by an event"? @FaneDuru

Comment: Simple workbook `Open` event, `Activate` event, `SheetActivate` or/and something else. If the workbook is closed and then reopen, who will call the protecting procedure? In order to be sure that it will work when needed, many such events must check the status. A `Public` variable where the status will be kept (it may be Boolean, Date, composed string or whatever) will also help. When such an event is triggered it will just check the status variable and call the function according to what it finds inside that...

Comment: Oh I agree. But seeing how OP made no effort by writing some code himself, I'll let them to figure that out

Comment: Not a problem with me... I tried to give him some (similar) hints in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Tim Stack for answer - I modified it a little bit for anyone interested in the future:

@FaneDuru - the must be called by an event you mentioned works because the code is running on "ThisWorkbook" In Excel VBA which means that it get's called everytime the workbook is opened.

```
Option Explicit
Function unlockwb()
Dim pw

pw = "xxx"
' Unprotect WB structure
ThisWorkbook.Unprotect pw
' Unrotect sheet
Sheet1.Unprotect pw

End Function
Function lockwb()
Dim pw

pw = "xxx"
' Protect WB structure
ThisWorkbook.Protect pw, True, True
' Protect sheet
Sheet1.Protect pw

End Function
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim weekdaylock, timelowerbound, timeupperbound, pw
pw = "xxx"

weekdaylock = vbFriday
If Weekday(Date) = weekdaylock Then
    lockwb
End If

timelowerbound = TimeValue("08:00:00")
timeupperbound = TimeValue("12:00:00")
' Or both
If Weekday(Date) = weekdaylock Then
    If timelowerbound < Time() And Time() < timeupperbound Then
        If InputBox("Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password") <> pw Then
            MsgBox "Wrong Password"
            lockwb
            ThisWorkbook.Close
        Else
            unlockwb
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you could upvote answers if you find them useful, or accept them if they answered the question..

Comment: @TimStack  Accepted, can't upvote because: Too low of a reputation :( altough it said it's counted but not displayed.

Comment: Is your workbook open each day ore more times per day? If not, this code will not work as expected.

Comment: The code must stay in a sub and be called from an evaluation sub called by some events. Only workbook `Open` event may be not enough. The evaluation sub must calculate the time period from the current time until the moment you intend to protect the workbook and call the protection itself code using `Applications.OnTime`. Your code evaluates only the moment when the event triggering...